# Forward Slash Key stops working on Deepin Linux

Tags: keyboard, deepin

I've started using Deepin Linux recently and theres a nagging problem I'm experiencing. After some time I'm using the laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T440s) the key <kbd>/</kbd> stops working.

I ran `XEV` on both scenarios:

- Working:

  ````
      root 0x12f, subw 0x0, time 2602403, (1417,174), root:(3018,215),
      state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
      XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 97
      XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
      XFilterEvent returns: False```
  ````
- Not working:

  ````
      root 0x12f, subw 0x0, time 5752135, (747,743), root:(2348,784),
      state 0x4, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False```
  ````

I don't know exactly why or when this happens. What I know is that if I logout and login back again, the key resumes working.

The keyboard layout I'm using is `Portuguese (Brazil, ThinkPad da IBM/Lenovo)` / `IBM ThinkPad R60/T60/R61/T61`.

Any help regarding preventing this to happen or how to make the key work again without logging in and out would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste more xev info while working/not working? Ideally, the press/release events for any other key (say "a"), on top of the press/release events for "/". Also, did you do any customization to .Xmodmap?